# JAVA API performance testing using GRINDER

Tags: grinder

i'm not sure if GRINDER is still best tool so far JAVA API performance testing tool. If anyone is using it, could you share your feedback? tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used JMeter and Grinder and can tell you that grinder is awesome . JMeter is also great . Not sure why you will be testing a JAVA API.
Grinder is more like a programmers performance tester tool. Once you get a hang of it you will not lean away from it . The only complex part could be the recorded scripts that grinder generates .The initial recorded script can get you overwhelmed and you might think what have i picked up .
But actually it just a step by step script and easy to modify as per your needs.
Any performance testing will have only these steps .

- Record - Generates the Initial Script of what you want to test.
- Modify - Modify it as per you needs.For grinder you may require a basic knowledge of some scripting language. Many times this may not be required.
- Test - Put the load you want to .Here you need to decide the number of threads plus agents .

My vote is for grinder specially for complicated scenarios.